# different between class name vs self calling in super()

Tags: python, class, oop, pytorch, super

isn't it same meaning of class name NeuralNet and self keyword passing in super call  -
`super(`**NeuralNet**`,`**self**`).__init__() # init super`

here is the code snippet from example:

```py
class NeuralNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, use_batch_norm, input_size=784, hidden_dim=256, output_size=10):
        """
        Creates a PyTorch net using the given parameters.
        """
        super(NeuralNet, self).__init__() # init super
        # continues code
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your question, I kindly but very strongly suggest you do the *full* [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial).

And no, `NeuralNet` and `self` are NOT the same thing. The first is the `NeuralNet` **class**, the second is the current `NeuralNet` **instance** ("current": the one on which the method has been called).